# How much different is dynamic programming from recursion

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

Mostly I have heard that if you can make a recursion code , you can convert it to a Dynamic programming code, but what is the need to do the same ? And how to convert a recursion code to DP ?

Answer (score 0):

In dynamic programming there are 2 approaches, top-down and bottom-up.
lets take Fibonacci sequence as an example:
f(0) = 0 : x = 1,
f(1) = 1 : x = 1,
f(x) = f(x-1) + f(x-2) : x > 1
**The top-down approach:**
It uses recursion + memoization(storing the calculated states to avoid the recalculation):

```
int memo[1000];//initialized by zeroes

int f(int x) {
    if (x == 0 || x == 1) return 1;
    if (memo[x] != 0) return memo[x]; //trying to avoid recalculation
    memo[x] = f(x - 1) + f(x - 2); //storing the result
    return memo[x];
}
```

As you notice here to calculate the value f(x) we have to break it down into
f(x-1) and f(x-2), this why it is called top-down.
**The bottom-up approach:**
It uses loops(for,while...) rather than recursion and stores the values inside an array:

```
int memo[1000];

int bottom_up(int x) {
    memo[0] = 1;
    memo[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < 1000; i++)
        memo[i] = memo[i - 1] + memo[i - 2];
}
```

As you notice we calculate the values of Fibonacci sequence starting from the smaller values up to the bigger ones and this is why it is called bottom-up.
Converting the code from recursion to loops is considered converting the recursive code to an iterative code.

The recursive code will call itself multiple times and you should know that each function call will be stored inside the stack of your memory, so it is preferred to use the iterative approach as it will be better for memory and performance.